# SQL String to query Access Database

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I'm having a little trouble with the command line of a oledb query on an access database.
I've tried a number of different syntaxes, both right in access and in my code.  The connection to the database is fine, the error comes when I try to fill the da, or when I run it as a query in access.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = 'This Text String';
```

When I run this in acces, I get a Data Type mismatch. Double quotes yields the same. I thought it was because of the spaces do I tried wrapping the Text String in square brackets thusly:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = [This Text String];
```

In Access this prompts "Enter Parameter Value" listing the parameter as "This Text String".

I've also tried using the Like operator:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn LIKE 'This Text String';
```

Whether with single or double quotes, this produces no errors, but also produces no results.  I've Tried CONTAINS which gives me a syntax error.

At this point I don't know what else to try.  what I'm trying to accomplish is:

> Return all the rows in 'MyTable' where the text in 'MyColumn' equals 'This Text String'

Can someone help me? I feel I'm overlooking something, possibly obvious.

---

Edit: Ahh... I'm not sure if this is the problem, but perhaps it will help.

I just realized that the column (MyColumn) that I'm trying to filter based upon, is not just plain text in access, it's actually a lookup of a column in another table.

Pehaps that's the issue, because the data type is not actually text, it's number (since it's a list).  Ok... how do I overcome that?

Comment: What's the column type?  What's the error?

Comment: Wow... quick reply!  That's what I just realized and edited the post.  The column containing 'This Text String' data type isn't text, it's number because it looks up the choices available from another column in another table.  Is there a way I can reference that, or do I need to know what the number of that item is in the containing table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the lookup table

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable INNER JOIN Lookup l on MyColumn = l.key and l.value =  'This Text String';
```